# Имитация клика при загрузке страницы

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){ 
$('#callbackcolorbx').click(); 
},6000); 
});
```

Есть код, который имитирует клик на ссылку при полной прогрузке страницы.
По идее стоит таймаут, а не интервал, но клик всё равно повторяется каждые 6 секунд. В чём может быть проблема?
p.s.
Кликнуть должно всего 1 раз, без повторений

---

проблема решена

Comment: Может быть страница перезагружается после завершения таймаута?

Comment: Да нет, не перезагружается)

Comment: Так же если не закрывать всплывающее каждые 6 сек окно(colorbox-node, мб знает кто), то оно настакивается и при закрытии сразу же всплывает следующее. Т.е. это уже значит, что страница не перезагружается(ибо тогда бы всех этих стаков не было)

Comment: Проверьте правильность работы setTimeout() на чистом примере - голая страница с кнопкой, текст в консоль на клик и setTimeout.